# How and why is the red kite bird disturbed by wind turbines?

Tags: birds, bird-behaviour

Recently my region in Germany had great success in bringing back the [red kite bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_kite). Unfortunately a few decided to stay near newly built wind turbines. Thus the turbines are turned off from time to time to protect the seldom animal. This made me wonder which circumstances disturb the red kite and lead to a shutdown of the wind turbines?

Comment: You mean *other* than a blade whipping around at 10s of km per second slicing the bird in half?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yes, and I even don't think that this is a reason since the turbines get shutdown from time to time only. If the red kite would be in danger to get cut it would be demolished completely.

Comment: Maybe it's the change in airflow caused by the turbines? Just a random thought.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few aspects:

- Collision: some birds are better than others at avoiding wind farms, but this is a risk.
- Noise: the noise from the turbine and blades unsettles and upsets animals and birds
- Movement: birds of prey are very sensitive to movement, and the unnatural and fast blade movement upsets their normal behaviour

This can lead to them failing to hunt correctly, problems in rearing young, and even problems in courtship. Read this [article](https://www.rspb.org.uk/our-work/our-positions-and-campaigns/positions/windfarms/) and others on the rspb website.

Comment: Years back studies with the big test turbines in Orkney didn't seem to show any negative effects, but the RSPB and others have steadily gained more information on this, which is why location choice now considers not just the wind generation aspects but also the local bird life.